# Redirection in .htaccess?

Tags: redirect, joomla, virtuemart

I’d like to change the URL where a user is redirected after he submits a form.

In the .htaccess I wrote this:

```
Redirect 301 /component/virtuemart/user/edit?Itemid=0 https://www.monsite.fr/component/virtuemart/cart?Itemid=0
```

But it doesn’t work…

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/component/virtuemart/user/edit?Itemid=0$ https://www.mon-site.fr/component/virtuemart/cart?Itemid=0 [R=301,L]
```

And it’s not working neither…

What mistakes did I do?
How could I manage that?

Thanks for your help
Paul

Comment: does `RedirectPermanent urlA urlB` work ?

Comment: Unfortunately no…

Comment: None of these 3 redirections worked… What could be the reason?
For the second one I didn’t wrote any RewriteCond. Is it needed?

Comment: [Check that maybe could help](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file#:~:text=301%20(Permanent)%20Redirect%3A,%22example.com%22%20domain.)

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.